# switching from NewID to Sequential NewID for a default PK value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a production database with few million rows all using randomly generated GUIDs using a default value of `NewID()` as the primary key.

I am thinking of using the Sequential NewIDs going forward.

How will SQL Server know while generating the GUIDs in sequence that it did not already create that GUID when it was randomly generating using `NEWID()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're considering using [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) as the new default value.

Don't worry about the scenario of duplicates. The PK constraint on that column guarantees that a collision isn't going to happen. You aren't guaranteed that a new sequential GUID will be 'higher' anyway:

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. After restarting Windows, the **GUID can start again from a lower range**, but is still globally unique.

Some relevant information that may help you at [Microsoft Connect : NEWSEQUENTIALID() is Not Sequential](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/475131/newsequentialid-is-not-sequential)